# How to adjust font size of a label according to length of string and label size

Tags: ios, swift

I have a multi line label with a set size (300 x 300).

I want to adjust the label's font size programmatically according to how long the label's text is and how big the label is.

Here are 2 examples of the same sized labels with different length text strings
[image: short text]

[image: long text]

Comment: Please show the attempts you have already made at solving this yourself.

Comment: You can change the font size according to the length of string that you are assigning to the label. You have methods for setting font size programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to `NSString.boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:`. Here you need to decrement the font size stepwise until the string will fit into the original frame.

```
var paragraph = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
let layout = [NSFontAttributeName:NSFont.systemFontOfSize(0), NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraph, ]
paragraph.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
var a = NSString(string: "My long text")
let rect = NSMakeSize(30, 20)
let bb = a.boundingRectWithSize(rect, options: NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: layout)
```

Place the above in Playground and modify `rect` and the font to see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

I know the Question is old but....

Just use the option AutoShrink and set the minimum font size/scale in the Attributes Inspector, it will scale the font as large as possible to fit the size of the label.

[image]